How to calculate factor return given a barra model and individual stock returns?
Assuming that we have k factors and n stocks
Then Barra provides a k x k factor covariance matrix F, and a k x n factor exposure matrix E.
At runtime, we also observed a n x 1 vector r of individual stock return
My question is, how should we calculate the k x 1 vector of factor return f?
r =  E^t * f

or
r = E^t * F * f

basically, we need to solve a regression problem to get f . But I am not sure which of these 2 formula should I use.
IIRC it should be the second form, but I am not so sure.
Can someone please help to clarify?
Thanks

IMHO, without additional risk sources, this looks like an exercise in linear algebra.
Given observed $r$ of dimension $n\times 1$, known $E$ of dimension $k \times n $ and unknown $f$ of dimension $k \times 1$, where $k\leq n$, we find:
$$
\begin{align}
r&=E^Tf\\
\Rightarrow\left(EE^T\right)^{-1}Er&=f
\end{align}
$$

thanks. my question was actually, which of the following 2 functions is correct?
it was
r = E^t * F * f
or
r = E^t * F * f
should we include the factor covariance F ?

If you add the covariance matrix to the mix, you obtain orthonormalized factor returns. I do not have good knowledge about what is "right" there.

if we do not include F, we will have raw factor return as in bps, right ?

Hi: you need to multiply the $k \times n$ factor exposure matrix by the factor returns estimated from the previous month which is a $1 \times k$ vector. Call it $FR$. Barra used to provide them and probably still does ? Then $FR \times E$ will give you an estimate of the total systematic factor return due to each stock.

@Kermittfrog  I was just curious if you ever worked out your question ? They definitely did provide monthly factor returns ( to be used in performance attribution ) at one point in time but maybe things have changed. At the time, I think they were lagged one month so, if you were in December, the latest monthly factor return was the November factor return.

Hi @markleeds, I think you meant to address this comment towards eight3, no?

Hi Kermittfrog: oops. my mistake. I looked up and saw Kermittfrog and thought you were the questioner. hopefully eight3 sees it anyway. thanks for correction and apologies for noise.

Fit a linear regression model where y = r and X = E'. As you said,
r =  E^t * f

The coefficients of the linear model will be f.
